# increment counter when value occurs more than once

Tags: php

An example output of the following code may be this:

39 48 39 12 17 39 12

code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($filterResult)) {
while ($filterrow = mysql_fetch_array($filterResult)) {

$vidID = $filterrow['routineID'];
...
...
echo "<video id='video$vidID'></video>";
  }
}
```

I need it to output like this:

39 48 39_1 12 17 39_2 12_1

Notice how value 39 occurs three times and value 12 occurs twice. 
After the first occurence of a value I need it
formatted like ##_#.

Can you help me code this up?
I appreciate your time and assistnace -
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($filterResult)) {
  $tmp = array();
  while ($filterrow = mysql_fetch_array($filterResult)) {

     $vidID = $filterrow['routineID'];

     if(isset($tmp[$vidID]) {
        $tmp[$vidID] = $tmp[$vidID] + 1;
        $vidID = $vidID . '_' . $tmp[$vidID];
     } else {
        $tmp[$vidID] = 0;
     }

     echo $vidID;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Frederic, this is close. Erroneous data begins to show up when the array gets larger. Look at the output from this link (notice how the logic starts out correct but then look at the format of the last three IDs) http://www.realcardio.com/playMyWorkout.php?ID=12,12,12,12,12,12,7,7,7,7,24,27,28,28

Comment: I think this did it! (I'll do a few more tests)                     if (mysql_num_rows($filterResult)) {
  $tmp[]=0;
  while ($filterrow = mysql_fetch_array($filterResult)) {
       $vidID = $filterrow['routineID'];
         if(isset($tmp[$vidID])) {
            $tmp[$vidID] = $tmp[$vidID] + 1;
            $vidID = $vidID . '_' . $tmp[$vidID];
           } else {
            $tmp[$vidID] = "";
           }

Comment: ok glad it worked for you, I made a simple test with an array, my logic seems ok.I think that you should not initialize the $tmp this way ($tmp[]=0) as you will get an error if you have a '0' in your list : for example : 0,1,12,12,12,12,12,12,7,7,7,7,24,27,28,28  yields 0_1 wich is not the  expected result

Answer (score 3):

Use array_count_values like this:-

```
$array = array(1, 38, 1, 38,35);
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [38] => 2
    [35] => 1
)
```

Apply some logic to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($filterResult)) {
while ($filterrow = mysql_fetch_array($filterResult)) {
$j=-1;
$vidID = $filterrow['routineID'];
$arr[]=$vidID;
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
if($arr[$i]==$vidID)
$j++;
}
if($j==0)
$j="";
else $j="_".$j;
echo $vidID.$j;
 }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work and it's close. I've discovered a strange issue with the for loop that I don't know how to resolve. It never prints the second position in the array. If my dataset looks like 4,4,78,54,23,23,23 it will print 4,78,54,23,23_1,23_2. I spent some time troubleshooting it but I can't figure it out. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$array1 = array(39,48,39,12,17,39,12);
$array2 = array(39,48,39,12,17,39,12);

foreach($array1 as $value){

  $counts1 = array_count_values($array1);
  $counts2 = array_count_values($array2);

  if(!empty($counts2[$value])){

    if ($counts1[$value] > 1){

      $count = $counts1[$value] - $counts2[$value] + 1;

              if($count > 1) {

                 echo $value.'_'.($count - 1).' ';
              } else {

                 echo $value.' ';
              }
    } else {

      echo $value.' ';
    }
    array_shift($array2);
  }
}
```

Here is the [PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2i4-dy3)

Comment: I like what you've done but the data in the array will always be different. The data is being queried from a database.

Comment: It does't matter. You can pass any data as array1 and array2. If the numbers are not array, you can split the string into array by str_split($string) function. When I answered, you have not mentioned about database code hence the above answer given.